# Referencing cell in workbook with variable name

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with a macro that creates a copy of a worksheet and names it with the current date. name of new worksheet is captured in first worksheet. How can I reference a cell in the second worksheet. Obviously I cant do something like "16122014!A1" as the name of the worksheet will change each time the macro runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're naming them with the format `ddmmyyyy`, so you can build a string from today's date in the same format, and then use Excel's [Indirect](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151323) function to use it as a reference.

> =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(TEXT(TODAY(), "ddmmyyyy"), "!A1"))

This gets today's date, formats it as Text with the format "ddmmyyyy", concatenates this newly made date text with the text "!A1" (cell to reference on the other sheet), then uses Indirect to reference the cell (based on the text we created/provided).

If the name of the sheet is actually held in a cell on the first sheet (i.e. in cell Z33), you could us Indirect and just reference that cell's contents:

> =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(Z33, "!A1"))

Comment: And, of course, if the sheet name might contain spaces or other special characters, surround it with single quotes (e.g., `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'", Z33, "'!A1"))`).